# Change xAxis and yAxis title of drilldown chart after entering into second series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I drew a drilldown chart and I don't know how to change both x-Axis and y-Axis title after clicking the bars and go to second chart. Also how to change to default title after clicking drillUp button and go back to first chart.

For example, I want my **first chart**'s **x-Axis** title to be **"Percentage Arange"** and **y-Axis** title to be **"Number of Schools"**. And **second chart**'s x-Axis title to be **"School Name"** and yAxis title to be **"Percentage"**.

I searched for some related code. There is one about how to change the title of the drilldown chart:

```
var defaultTitle = "Basic drilldown";
var drilldownTitle = "More about ";
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    renderTo: 'container',
    events: {
        drilldown: function(e) {
            chart.setTitle({ text: drilldownTitle + e.point.name });
        },
        drillup: function(e) {
            chart.setTitle({ text: defaultTitle });
        }
    }
},
title: {
    text: defaultTitle
},
// ... more options});
```

However, i don't know how to use for my case.

Here is the code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Basic drilldown'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: "Percentage Range"
    }
  },
  yAix: {
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: "Number of Schools"
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      grouping: false,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Things',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0,
    data: [{
      name: '100-70%',
      y: 5,
      drilldown: '100-70%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Things',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0.1,
    data: [{
      name: '70-30%',
      y: 2,
      drilldown: '70-30%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Things',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0.3,
    data: [{
      name: '30-0%',
      y: 4,
      drilldown: '30-0%'
    }]
  }],
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
      id: '100-70%',
      data: [
        ['Cats', 4],
        ['Dogs', 2],
        ['Cows', 1],
        ['Sheep', 2],
        ['Pigs', 1]
      ]
    }, {
      id: '70-30%',
      data: [
        ['Apples', 4],
        ['Oranges', 2]
      ]
    }, {
      id: '30-0%',
      data: [
        ['Toyota', 4],
        ['Opel', 2],
        ['Volkswagen', 2]
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: You can use Axis.update() function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.update). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cypuydv0/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look through the docs [Axis.setTitle](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setTitle)

```
var defaultTitleXAxis = "Percentage Range";
var defaultTitleYAxis = "Number of Schools";
var drilldownTitleXAxis = "School Name";
var drilldownTitleYAxis = "Percentage";
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
        drilldown: function(e) {
            this.xAxis[0].setTitle({ text: drilldownTitleXAxis });
            this.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: drilldownTitleYAxis });
        },
        drillup: function(e) {
            this.xAxis[0].setTitle({ text: defaultTitleXAxis });
            this.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: defaultTitleYAxis });
        }
    }
  },
  //....... remaining code
 })
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/otm4mnjx/) demo